# ios8 specific alerts for specific contacts

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts, notifications

I'm currently using a blackberry 9900. I use it for work and personal. I have different ring/notification profiles setup. When at work I have it on vibrate or silent but if I receive a text or email from a specific contact then I get an audible alert. Actually this works for any profile I have active; text or email from a specific contact will always push thru. I also have certain contacts who if the call me, I will get a push thru notification but not if they text/email.

Bottom Line - does ios8 allow specific contacts the ability to push thru no matter what the active notification profile is? I need to be able to specify the specific notification ie text vs email vs phone and have different alerts.

This is a make it or break it decision for me

Answer (score 1):

iOS doesn't use profiles.

The equivalent would be to set to Do Not Disturb, & set specific contacts to be allowed through.
Each contact can have a specific ringtone & text/iMessage alert tone, built-in or custom.

Other contacts can get through if you set to notify if they ring twice in quick succession, otherwise your phone just holds all incoming messages until you wish to view them; phone calls go to voicemail.

Comment: Can a contact have a push thru notification for text but not email? These are life or death notifications for when I'm on call at the hospital. If I leave my phone on with all notifications going thru then I get no sleep. But I cannot miss a page aka text or call from the hospital.

Comment: I'm not sure about email, tbh. I have POP email which can't push, only fetch - so I have to manually launch Mail to get it.

Comment: What I mean is if I get an email (IMAP) or text or call from hospital locating, it will trigger an audible notification even if my phone is on silent or DND

Comment: I really don't know & cannot test